# Trouble with vertical line between two divs'

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a vertical line that divides two div's with the word OR in the middle of the line(s). I'd like the vertical lines to span the entire height, instead they are currently 1px each. The css needs to be responsive and the height of the form fields does change depending on the selection, so I can't use fixed height.

[image]

```
<section>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">FORM FIELDS LEFT</div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <div class="col-md-12 v-separator"></div>
         <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: center">OR</div>
         <div class="col-md-12 v-separator"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">FORM FIELDS RIGHT</div>
   </div>
</section>
```

```css
.col-md-2,.col-md-5,.col-md-12 
{
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   min-height:1px;
   padding-right:15px;
   padding-left:15px
}
.col-md-2{width:16.66666667%}
.col-md-5{width:41.66666667%}
.col-md-12{width:100%}
.v-separator
{
  left:50%;
  top:10%;
  bottom:10%;
  border-left:1px solid black;
}
.row{margin-right:-15px;margin-left:-15px}
.row:after,.row:before{display:table;content:" "}
.row:after{clear:both}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using `:before` and `:after` on the parent div or section to create the line and OR. I've changed `.col-md-5` to `.col-md-6` so each takes up 50% of the parent. This way you don't need unnecessary html elements, it grows with the height automatically, and it's perfectly centered within the parent. You'll need to adjust the divs with the form fields in them for spacing.

*EDIT FOR COMMENT*

For small screens, if the heights are equal, you can change the `:before` to have `width: auto; height: 1px`.

If the heights aren't equal and because the line shows up exactly in the middle, you'll want to use these in a media query (`@media (min-width: 600px){}` or whatever width they are side by side) to only show when they are side by side. If they aren't equal height, you can still mimic this at smaller sizes by using border-bottom on the top div.

```css
.row:after,.row:before{display:table;content:""}
.row:after{clear:both}

.v-separator .col-md-6:first-child {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
padding-bottom: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
position: relative;
}

.v-separator .col-md-6:first-child:after {
content: 'OR';
display: block;
color: black;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
bottom: -15px;
background: white;
padding: 3px;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 600px){
.col-md-2,.col-md-6,.col-md-12 
{
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   min-height:1px;
   padding-right:15px;
   padding-left:15px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col-md-2{width:16.66666667%}
.col-md-6{width:45%;}
.col-md-6 + .col-md-6 {float: right;}
.col-md-12{width:100%}

.v-separator .col-md-6:first-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.v-separator .col-md-6:first-child:after {
    display: none;
}

/* added v-separator:before, :after and position: relative below */
.v-separator:before {
    content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top:10%;
  bottom:10%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
}

.v-separator:after
{
    content: 'OR';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: white;
    padding: 3px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.v-separator {position: relative;}

.row{position: relative;margin-right:-15px;margin-left:-15px}
}
```

```html
<section class="v-separator">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          FORM FIELDS LEFT<br>
          FORM FIELDS LEFT<br>
          FORM FIELDS LEFT<br>
          FORM FIELDS LEFT<br>
          FORM FIELDS LEFT<br>
          FORM FIELDS LEFT
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          FORM FIELDS RIGHT<br>
          FORM FIELDS RIGHT<br>
          FORM FIELDS RIGHT<br>
          FORM FIELDS RIGHT<br>
          FORM FIELDS RIGHT<br>
          FORM FIELDS RIGHT
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works on everything but a small screen size. Any way to get it to disappear or go horizontal when the screen size gets smaller? Either way, I'll award you the points when I'm able.

Comment: I've updated the answer to accommodate screens where the divs are stacked. It will depend on the height of the divs. You can change the height and width of the divider if you know the heights will be equal. If not, you can either use a `border-bottom`  and `:after` on the top div like in the updated answer or you can `display: none` on both the `:before` and `:after` on smaller screens.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a vertically repeating 1px background on the middle column. Something like:

```
.your-class {
  background: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=') repeat-y 50%;
}
```

Comment: How do I get the background to span the entire height of the parent div?

Comment: Assigning the class to the parent div instead of the child div would ensure that

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat changed your HTML for [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0abtho22/1/), but only have 1 seperator and have a span with a white background and center it.

Basically we're putting a border on the right column and absolute positioning the span, so it looks split.

On the fiddle I added a `height` on the `.col-md-6` but that's just for display purposes. I'm assuming that both your divs will be the same height

```
<section>
<div class="row" id="some-container"> 
     <span id="seperator">OR</span>
    <div class="col-md-6">FORM FIELDS LEFT</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="right">FORM FIELDS RIGHT</div>
</div>
</section>

#some-container {
  position: relative;
}
#right {
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
 }
#some-container #seperator {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```